# Apache module mpm_worker + php issue

Tags: php, apache, apache2, preforking

I am using php and apache in ubuntu machine and trying multi threading concepts.
Apache comes with defaut "prefork" module.
And When I enable mpm_worker module , Php stops working..

Do I need to enable any other modules to make php working when mpm_worker enabled in apache.

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if anyone faces the same issue check this article:

```
1. Install apache2-mpm-worker and the fastcgi apache module libapache-mod-fcid

Code:
# apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker  libapache2-mod-fcgid2. Enable the Fastcgi apache module mod_fcgid

Code:
# sudo a2enmod fcgid3. Install php5-cgi and the command-line version php5-cli


Code:
# sudo aptitude install php5-cgi php5-cli4. Add the following to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf or place these basic configuration settings in a file under /etc/apache2/conf.d. For example, /etc/apache2/conf.d/00-myconf ("00-" will help insure it is read first before other /etc/apache2/conf.d files, which is necessary).    

Code:
<Directory /var/www>
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 .php
Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
# If you have Aliases provide php support for them (Here we provide php support for scripts in /usr/share's subdirectories)
Alias /aptitude /usr/share/doc/aptitude/html/en
Alias /apt /usr/share/doc/apt-doc

<Directory /usr/share>
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 .php
Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks Indexes
</Directory>5. Then, for each virtual host configuration file you have in /etc/apache2/sites-available, add ExecCGI within a <Directoy /path-to-site> block (placed within your <VirtualHost> block). For example, 

# cat /etc/apache2/sites-availabe/yourdomain.com

Code:
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin youremail@yourdomain.com
ServerName yoursite.tld
ServerAlias www.yourdomain.tld *.yourdomain.tld

DocumentRoot /var/www/yourdomain.com

ErrorLog        /var/log/apache2/yourdomain.tld-error.log
CustomLog       /var/log/apache2/yourdomain.tld-access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/yourdomain.com>
Options +ExecCGI 

AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
allow from all
</Directory>
LogLevel warn
ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>Note: ExecCGI was turned on in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default for /var/www and its subdirectories, so it is not strictly necessary within the <VirtualHost > block shown here. Using +ExecCGI adds fastcgi support to the Options in force. Options don't merge with prior options (they replace them) unless + is used. You can specify entirely different Options, but you must at a minmum have ExecCGI, if you want php support for your virtual host.

6. For any other <Directory /some/other/path> blocks you have, say, for virtual hosts, which are not subdirectories of /var/www or /usr/share, add 

<Directory /some/other/path>
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 .php
Options +ExecCGI 
# add other Options you might need, but ExecCGI is required
# . . .
</Directory>

7. Enable your virtual host    

Code:
#sudo a2ensite yourdomain.com7. And reload the apache configuration

Code:
# sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reloador just restart apache2

Code:
# sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```